# how to display the records with images to jsp from oracle

Tags: java

all I working with one project called alumni information system where I want to store all information about students i.e. name, phone number, mail id, photo. And whenever by clicking on one link i.e. view all students information. then I want to display total information about student on jsp page i.e. name, phone number, mail id, image...

I Have searched in the net also.  I am not getting correct answer. So please reply to my question.... Thanks in advances

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the physical files that are the images reachable through your webapp.  Then, in your JSPs, you are just setting up Image tags (HTML ) to point to the files.

Your question is a little short of details.

Comment: But for storing physical files also in the webapp it needs file absolute path. I am not getting the absolute path of file to next page i.e. to store the data in database